# Blazor with JsRuntine Interop

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm trying to invoke a javascript function in a Blazor component, but with no success.

The error is:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: Could not find 'FullCalendarInterop.init' ('FullCalendarInterop' was undefined).
> Error: Could not find 'FullCalendarInterop.init' ('FullCalendarInterop' was undefined).
> at https://localhost:7065/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:328
> at Array.forEach ()
> at a.findFunction (https://localhost:7065/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:296)
> at _ (https://localhost:7065/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:2437)
> at https://localhost:7065/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:3325
> at new Promise ()

Component structure:

[image]

Razor page:

```
@using Microsoft.JSInterop
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime
    
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
   var options = new CalendarOptions
   {
      Id = Id,
      DefaultView = View,
      CalendarEvents = Events.Where(r => r.Status == CalendarEventStatus.Active).ToList()
   };
    
   var dotNetObjectReference = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
   var fullCalendarInterop = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Shared/InputCalendar.razor.js");
   await fullCalendarInterop.InvokeVoidAsync("FullCalendarInterop.init", options, dotNetObjectReference);

// I already just tried^
// await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("FullCalendarInterop.init", options, DotNetObjectReference.Create(this));
    
  await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);}
```

Javascript

```
var FullCalendarInterop = function () {
    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function (options, dotNetReference) {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById(options.id);
            var calendar = new window.FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                plugins: ['interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list'],

                isRTL: window.KTUtil.isRTL(),
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
                },

                height: 800,
                contentHeight: 750,
                aspectRatio: 3,  // see: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/aspectRatio

                views: {
                    dayGridMonth: { buttonText: 'month' },
                    timeGridWeek: { buttonText: 'week' },
                    timeGridDay: { buttonText: 'day' },
                    listWeek: { buttonText: 'list' }
                },

                defaultView: options.defaultView,
                defaultDate: options.defaultDate,

                editable: true,
                eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
                navLinks: true,
                events: options.calendarEvents,

                eventRender: function (info) {
                    var event = $(info.event);
                    var element = $(info.el);
                    var view = $(info.view);

                    if (info.event.extendedProps && info.event.extendedProps.description) {
                        if (element.hasClass('fc-day-grid-event')) {
                            element.data('content', info.event.extendedProps.description);
                            element.data('placement', 'top');
                            window.KTApp.initPopover(element);
                        } else if (element.hasClass('fc-time-grid-event')) {
                            element.find('.fc-title').append('<div class="fc-description">' + info.event.extendedProps.description + '</div>');
                        } else if (element.find('.fc-list-item-title').lenght !== 0) {
                            element.find('.fc-list-item-title').append('<div class="fc-description">' + info.event.extendedProps.description + '</div>');
                        }
                    }

                    element.find(".fc-bg").css("pointer-events", "none");
                    element.find(".fc-list-item-title.fc-widget-content").prepend(
                        "<span style='position: absolute; right: 5px;'>" +
                        "<button class='btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-circle btn-light' " +
                        "style='height: 16px; width: 16px;' id='calendar_del_" + event.id + "'>" +
                        "<i class='icon-xs text-dark-50 flaticon2-cross'></i></button></span>");
                    element.find(".fc-content").append("<span style='position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px;'>" +
                        "<button class='btn btn-icon btn-xs btn-circle btn-light' " +
                        "style='height: 16px; width: 16px;' id='calendar_del_" + event.id + "'>" +
                        "<i class='icon-xs text-dark-50 flaticon2-cross'></i></button></span>");
                    element.find("#calendar_del_" + event.id).click(function () {
                        var eventId = event[0]._def.defId;
                        var eventIdentifier = event[0]._def.extendedProps.identifier;

                        //Remove popover
                        removeContent(".popover.fade.show.bs-popover-top");
                        //$(".popover.fade.show.bs-popover-top").remove();

                        dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('CalendarEventDeleted', eventIdentifier);
                        //$("#candidate_calendar").fullCalendar('removeEvents', eventId);
                    });
                },
                viewSkeletonRender: function (info) {
                    var view = $(info.view);
                    var defaultView = view[0].type !== null ? view[0].type : "";

                    dotNetReference.invokeMethodAsync('SetDefaultView', defaultView);
                    //alert(defaultView);
                }
            });

            calendar.render();
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: Does it work if you put the js in your wwwroot folder?

Comment: I think you may have to "export" your JS function? Instead of using JS Isolation, I just put my JS in a common .js file in the wwwroot folder that's linked up via the layout. Then you can just call the function without having to import the .js file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your .JS file like so:

```
var FullCalendarInterop = function () {
    return {
        //main function to initiate the module
        init: function (options, dotNetReference) {
            ... Trimmed for brevity ...
            calendar.render();
        }
    };
}();

export { FullCalendarInterop };
```

I added `();` to the end of your `FullCalendarInterop` function and then added the export. That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

As it says its a null reference error as you are not initializing JSmodule,

```
 IJSObjectReference fullCalendarInterop;
fullCalendarInterop = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./Shared/InputCalendar.razor.js");
```